# DoubleTab CupertinoBottomNavigationBar to get to home page

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am using the CupertinoBottomNavigationBar in my app. Everything works well, however there is one feature I would like to implement. Taking Spotify as an example, you can push to new screens within an item of the BottomNavBar and always return to the starting page by double tapping the BottomNavigationBar.
Is there a way to implement this in flutter?

```
class CupterinoBottomNav extends StatelessWidget {
  const CupterinoBottomNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home_filled,
                size: 28,
              ),
              label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.text_fields_sharp,
                size: 28,
              ),
              label: 'Test'),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) => const Homepage());
          case 1:
          default:
            return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) => const Test());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A sample video of Spotify feature will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InkWell widget to listen for the double tap and then there are a couple of ways to navigate home to your home page. One way would be to use [name routes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) and then navigate home using:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I‘ll try that. Should also be working with a GestureDetector